# Is that redundant for groups=0(root) listed in id command output?

Tags: users, root, group

```
sudo id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

Maybe it is redundant  for groups=0(root) listed here, gid=0(root) can express the meaning of group **root**'s id is 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the `id` command lists is

1. The effective user ID and username of the user running `id`,
2. The effective group ID and group name of same user,
3. The list of all supplementary ("secondary") groups that this user belongs to.

In this case, the `root` user belongs to only one group, the `root` group, so this group is listed as the effective group as well as part of the supplementary groups.

On my OpenBSD system:

```
$ doas id
uid=0(root) gid=0(wheel) groups=0(wheel), 2(kmem), 3(sys), 4(tty), 5(operator), 20(staff), 31(guest)
```

Answer (score 2):

The result of `id` provides three values `ugG` (id and name together) by default.

From Linux man page,

> -u, --user : Print only the effective user ID
>
> -g, --group : Print only the effective group ID
>
> -G, --groups : Print all group IDs

Here `groups=0(root)` represent that the user `root` belongs to a group called `root`. Since there are no secondary groups for `root` here, it looks like a redundant information.

For a user who belongs to multiple groups, the output would look like

```
uid=492(username) gid=492(primary groupname) groups=492(primary group), 493(secondary group)
```